Problem with Nuxt Authentication in Production
I am trying to deploy a nuxt application in a server. The server uses nginx and acts as proxy to localhost. Everything seems fine, I can already access the appliaction with the domain of the server and I can make api calls to the server. However, the authentication does not work. I am using sidebase nuxt auth and when I am trying to login an user I get the error shown in the image.
Error in the browser's console after an user tries to authenticate
To run the server I use pm2 and this is the ecosystem.config.cjs file:
module.exports = {
    apps: [
    {
    name: 'eurocore-coopetition',
    port: '3000',
    exec_mode: 'cluster',
    instances: '1',
        script: './.output/server/index.mjs'
    }
    ]
}
  

And this is my nuxt.config.ts file:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  modules: [
    (_options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) => {
        // @ts-expect-error
        config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true }))
      })
    },
    '@sidebase/nuxt-auth'
    //...
  ],
  vite: {
    vue: {
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls,
      },
    },
  },
  css: [
    '/assets/custom-theme.scss',
  ],
  auth: {
    baseURL: process.env.NUXT_AUTH_ORIGIN,
    globalAppMiddleware: true
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    authSecret: process.env.NUXT_AUTH_SECRET,
    registrationCode: process.env.NUXT_REGISTRATION_CODE,
  },
})

The auth origin is set to http://localhost:3000/ .
And this is my [...].ts file located in /server/api/auth:
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from "#auth"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

declare module "next-auth"{
  interface User {
    role: string
  }
}

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({token, user}) => {
      const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
      if (isSignIn){
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
        //token.jwt = user ? (user as any).acess_token || '' : '';
        //token.id = user ? user.id || '' : '';
        //token.role = user ? (user as any).role || '' : '';

      }
      return token;
    },

    session: async ({session, token}) => {
      (session as any).uid = token.id;
      (session as any).role = token.role;
      return session;
    }
  },
  secret: config.authSecret,
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    // @ts-expect-error
    CredentialsProvider.default({
      name: "Credentials",
      async authorize(credentials: {email: string, password: string}) {
        const user = await prisma.users.findUnique({where: { email: credentials.email }})
        let valid;
        if (user) {
          valid = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);
        }
        
        if(!user || !valid){
          throw createError({
            statusCode: 403,
            statusMessage: "Credentials not working",
          })
        }
        return user
      },
    }),
  ],
})

I have tried to change the baseURL to the domain of the server but that did not work and it did not load any page. In development mode everything works if I test the deployment in my computer using pm2 it also works. So I don't know what it's the problem.
Update!
I have tried to deploy another nuxt project that uses the same authentication and the problem persists. This is the nginx file. I managed to deploy project in vercel. I believe the problem persists in the baseURL but I already changed the environmental variable multiple times but with no success. I also tried to removed the quotation marks of the URL since this was a problem in vercel but the problem persists, i.e., the server can not resolve.
    server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
listen 8000 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:8000 ssl default_server;

server_name         example.com;

ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
#ssl_ciphers        !aNULL:!MD5
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    #proxy_redirect off;
    #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

Any help is appreciated!

Can you please replace the image with the browser error by the actual text?

Sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Try to set the auth origin to your actual domain https://your-domain instead of https://localhost
